# Using the C# Lambda Operator in a method signature

Tags: c#, lambda, operator-keyword

I have read about the lambda operator in C# doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator#code-try-0) about how it can be used in a c# signature or constructor. Still not enlightened. Can someone please explain what's going on in this method signature:

```
public SampleCustomer(string name, DateTime dateJoined)
    => (Name, DateJoined) = (name, dateJoined);
```

Comment: [Understand Lambda Expressions in 3 Minutes](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-Minutes) • [Anonymous Delegates for C#](https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/anonymous-delegates-csharp) • [Closures and the Lambdas](https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/closures-and-lambdas-csharp) • [Anatomy of the Lambda Expression](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-lambda-expression) • [Lambda Expressions in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bd6c67/lambda-expressions-in-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an example of constructor written using `=>` syntax. `=>` is similar to writing method as usual in `{ ... }`. What's happening here:

```cs
public SampleCustomer(string name, DateTime dateJoined) => (Name, DateJoined) = (name, dateJoined);
```

is equal to:

```cs
public SampleCustomer(string name, DateTime dateJoined)
{
    (Name, DateJoined) = (name, dateJoined);
}
```

After removing tuples it looks like:

```cs
public SampleCustomer(string name, DateTime dateJoined)
{
    Name = name;
    DateJoined = dateJoined;
}
```

So in this constructor some fields are assigned from values passed to it.

Comment: Thanks for a perfect answer, but is what you call => syntax  a term in C# or maybe in many other languages as well (a general term)?

Comment: In different languages `=>` could work in a different way. In C# and JS it's lambda, in C++ IIRC it is a different thing

Comment: It's just a syntax sugar for writing methods in C#

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to write a method, in your case, a constructor method.

Your class has (or inherits) these two properties `Name` and `DateJoined` Your constructor is receiving their values (using tuples) with the purpose of initialize these properties.

This is does the same thing, but your example is shorter.

```
public SampleCustomer(string name, DateTime dateJoined)
{
    Name = name;
    DateJoined = dateJoined;
}
```

The `=>` operator allows you to omit `{}`

Comment: Just a rant here: It is incredible that in the documentation, they managed to explain this phenomenomn like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator#expression-body-definition.

Comment: @netfed I can't work out whether you think it's amazing or terrible. I can't even work out what you think is amazing/terrible. Can something coded into a compiler and following a strict set of documented rules truly be called a "phenomenon"?

Comment: a fact or event of scientific interest susceptible to scientific description and explanation. Let's not go into a philosophical debate here. The question was thoroughly answered anyway.